# Trying to add a directory with various scripts to my PATH, but it is not running the script when called from outside the directory

Tags: shell, path

Update: Included a lot more relevant information, thank you for suggesting including this!

I am very new to Linux and I am trying to run scripts that someone else created. I recently learned about the `$PATH` variable, and realized that I need to add my scripts folder to my `$PATH` variable in order to make it callable from anywhere on the terminal. However, even when I add the folder containing my script to the `$PATH` variable, the script inside is not being recognized.

I have edited my bashrc file in a text editor, at the bottom to include:

```
#Modify $PATH
export PATH="/home/eli/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

My script is located in `/home/eli/bin`, if I don't specify the entire path, the script will not run despite this bin being in my $PATH variable.

So, here's my $PATH variable:

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ echo $PATH
/home/eli/miniconda3/bin:/home/eli/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Here are my script permissions:

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ ls -al ~/bin/trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eli eli 3064 May 19  2018 /home/eli/bin/trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl
```

Here is the output when I try to run the script without being in the directory or specifying the exact path to the file:

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ ./trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl
bash: ./trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try the export statement without the double quotes.

Comment: `ls $HOME/Scripts/2bRAD_Edwards_Lab` ? *"the directory is not found"* - please post the entire output. Bash couldn't have said that - it ignores PATHs which don't exist.

Comment: Please update the question with the *exact* command you run, the *exact* output you get and the output of some command to see this file, its permissions etc, like `ls -al path/to/the/scripts/script_name.sh`.

Comment: Note: This way you don't keep any previous PATH values. The usual way is to extend the existing PATH, whatever it is.

Comment: Thank you @thanasisp and Artem, I just added more information! I don't think I asked that clearly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want the shell to do a search for an executable in the directories listed in your `$PATH` variable, don't specify a path for the executable on the command line.

So, don't do

```
./trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl
```

as this does not make the shell look in `$PATH` at all (you gave the explicit path `./` for the executable).

Instead, use just

```
trim2bRAD_2barcodes_noAdap.pl
```

Also, when you add `/home/eli/bin` to the start of your `$PATH`, you can say

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

assuming `$HOME` will expand to `/home/eli`.  I.e., there is no need to list all directories in `$PATH` unless you want to set the variable to that very specific list of directories and/or don't trust the system to having given you a sane default.  You also do not need to export `PATH` as it is already an environment variable.